# R- producing a summary calculation for each column that is dependent on aggregations at a factor level

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a quantity of predictors each of type factor and a response/outcome column. I need to produce an overall measure for each predictor that is a summary of a calculation at a factor aggregated level.

I am hoping that someone could provide a rough solution on how to tackle this calculation without resorting to loops as I have done in the past.

**What I've tried so far**

Previously I have not performed a subsequent aggregation, and I relied on some pretty terrible R code where I loop through, producing a frequency table of goods and bads for each column, add the goods & bads totals, work out the contributions, then calculate the WoE.  This results in a table per column, so I'd then have to yet again loop through to sum up each WoE and store it in a table.

Since then I have started using plyr and can do basic summary and transform actions on data but this seems far outside of the basics.

**Calculation**

```
Weight of Evidence (WoE) = sum ( Factor-level WoEs )
```

Where each factor level WoE is calculated as `log(goodContribution/badContribution)`
and Contributions are defined as `Number of [goods] for factor / total number of [goods]`

**Example of the step by step calculation for a *single* column**

```
example<-data.frame(colA=factor(rep(letters[1:3],4)),
                    colB=factor(rep(letters[4:6],4)),
                    colC=factor(rep(letters[8:10],4)))

outcome<-factor(rep(c(1,0),6),labels=c("bad","good"))

wip <- as.data.frame(xtabs(formula = ~example$colA +  outcome))
wip <- dcast(wip, example.colA ~ outcome)
wip$badTotal<-sum(wip$bad)
wip$goodTotal<-sum(wip$good)
wip$badContribution<-wip$bad/wip$badTotal
wip$goodContribution<-wip$good/wip$goodTotal
wip$WOE<-log(wip$goodContribution/wip$badContribution)

outputs<-data.frame(col=c("colA"),WoE=sum(wip$WOE))
```

**UPDATES**

The WoE calculation comes out at 0 in the example.  In real life the calculation is more complex as add a small number (0.0001) to a good or bad total if it equals 0, so that we never pass a 0 or an Inf to the log.

I have included a single step of the calculation and added the results to output.  Previously, I would have looped through all columns and added the results to the outputs table to get all WoE.  For simplicity I did not want a loop structure interfering with the core code I had so previously written to calculate WoE.

Comment: Can you just tell us what the expected output for your sample data is? There's a lot going on in your code and I think it might be helpful to give us a formula and expected result.

Comment: outputs holds the values for one column - if I'd looped through the columns, or ran the code multiple times but with different columns I would append results after substituting colB for the current column name each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `data.table`. Note that I use `keyby` to order results by `outcome`, which spares me some headache later on. Also note that your input data has the unfortunate property of resulting in zero `WOE` for all entries.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(example)

totals = dt[, .N, keyby = outcome]
#   outcome N
#1:     bad 6
#2:    good 6

result = dt[, .N, keyby = list(colB, outcome)][,
              setNames(as.list(N/totals[,N]), totals[, outcome]), by = colB][,
              WOE := log(good/bad)]
result
#   colB       bad      good WOE
#1:    d 0.3333333 0.3333333   0
#2:    e 0.3333333 0.3333333   0
#3:    f 0.3333333 0.3333333   0
```

---

(edit by OP)
To make the code work on all rows and return a data.frame of the results use `lapply`:

```
#produce a list of results
result <- lapply(names(dt), function(colname){dt[,.N,keyby=c(colname,"outcome")][
  ,setNames(as.list(N/totals[,N]),totals[,outcome]),by=colname][
    ,WoE:=log(good/bad)][, list(colname,WoE=sum(WoE))]})

#collapse list into a data.table
rbindlist(result)
```

Comment: great stuff eddi. That is a much cleaner way of doing the calculation for a single column - I'll take a good read through the data.table documentation, but could you indicate how I would then do this for all columns and store sum(result$WOE) for each column? PS I'm aware that the example has results coming out at 0, but otherwise I would have had to introduce the small code snippet that adds a minor amount to a value to prevent 0 contributions and did not want to complicate matters.

Comment: @StephLocke just add a loop over the column names: `lapply(names(dt), function(colname) {dt[, .N, keyby = c(colname, "outcome")...})`

Comment: Cheers @eddi, I've produced some code to do the conversion based on your comment. You may be able to produce cleaner code, but so that the answer is complete I have submitted an edit of your answer with the extension. Feel free to improve on it, but I'll mark your answer as the answer once additional lines of code go on it.

Comment: @StephLocke thanks for the edit - I replaced the last `do.call(rbind` by a much better and faster `data.table` function. You can also avoid a couple of steps in the `results`, but this has more educational value.