# Loop through aggregation using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

So I'm I've tried to find the answer to this probably-obvious question.  I have multiple predictor variables that I need to loop through in order to get a summary of another column for each predictor.  This data frame will change with every iteration so I need code that work for multiple different data frames.  Here are the places I've looked so far:

[R- producing a summary calculation for each column that is dependent on aggregations at a factor level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927927/r-producing-a-summary-calculation-for-each-column-that-is-dependent-on-aggregat)

[Multiple data frame handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301453/multiple-data-frame-handling)

Using the mtcars package, this is what I've tried:

```
#get mtcars data from graphics package
install.packages("graphics")
library(graphics)
data <- mtcars 

#loop through names
variable <- list(colnames(data))
for(i in variable){
data1 <- data %>%
  group_by(i)
  summarise('number' = mean(mpg))
  }
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
 Column `i` is unknown
```

Not sure where to go next.

Comment: There are two problems.  You don't need to wrap with `list`.  You can use `group_by_at` for character elements i.e. `variable <- colnames(data)` and  `group_by_at(i)`  Third issue is that you are assigning the output to the same object i.e overwriting it.  INstead the 'data1' could be a list and fourth problem, there is no chain after the `group_by` with `summarise`

Comment: Ok.  I will experiment more. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @akrun.  How do I output to a dataframe for each column?

Comment: I posted as a solution.  Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code,

1) the `variable` is unnecessarily created as a `list`

2) Looping through the 'variable' is not getting inside the `list`, which is an issue from 1.

3) `group_by_at` can be used in place of `group_by` for `string` inputs

4) there is a typo of no connection ie. chain (`%>%`) between `group_by` and `summarise`

5) the output should be stored in a `list` or else it will be overwritten as we are assigning to the same object 'data1'

---

The below code does the correction

```
variable <- colnames(data) #is a `vector` now
data1 <- list() # initialize as a `list`
for(i in variable){ 
 data1[[i]] <- data %>%
     group_by_at(i) %>% #changed to `group_by_at`
   summarise(number = mean(mpg))
 }
```

Or this can be done in a `tidyverse` syntax which will return the output as a `list` of `tibble` and to avoid the initialization of `list` and assignment

```
purrr::map(variable, ~ data %>%
                          group_by_at(.x) %>%
                          summarise(number = mean(mpg)))
```

If we need to bind the `list` elements use `bind_rows`.  But, it would also create multiple columns as the first column name is different and fill with `NA`

```
purrr::map(variable, ~ data %>%
                      group_by_at(.x) %>%
                      summarise(number = mean(mpg))) %>%
                      set_names(variable) %>%
                      bind_rows(., .id = 'variable')
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun.  How can I get one tidy dataframe or tibble out of this?  So it would be the variable stacked on top of each other with the mean(mpg) for each?

Comment: @Jordan You can use `bind_rows`

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  One more question.  My real data set seems to give the first column as the list of variables as well as a column for each variable and finally the summarized data.  How to I collapse to one column being the variable, one column being each level with in the variable and then the summarized data.  
    i.e. 
    `insured age`    `23`     `44`
     `insured age`    `32`      `85`

Comment: @Jordan Not much clear from the comments.  If you have the first column as variables, then `variable <- as.character(data[,1])` then do `purrr::map(variable, ~ data[-1] %>% group_by_at(.x)%>%`